# Return list based on selected field

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need to return all fields on right that have the same field on the left, for exemple:
i select ***7Z19*** and return all list from right that have same field on left, like this example:

[image: Excel]

Thks in advance

Comment: Does your version of Excel support the `FILTER` formula?

Comment: Yes, i have this formula.

Comment: `=FILTER(B:B,A:A=H5)` or something similar.

Comment: Thks a lot, i dont know about FILTER

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=FILTER(B:B,A:A=H5) or something similar. – BigBen

Thks @BigBen

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have Excel office365 you could use:
`=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,SMALL(IF(A:A=E$5,ROW(A:A)),ROWS($1:1))),"")`
copy down the formula.

PS I used `E5` for the search value as your example does not mention the location. You may need to change the location to your needs (as well as column A and B).